# Wrapping huge equation without template dependencies

Tags: equations, mathtools

I am trying to reproduce this huge equation and have it wrap around like so:

[image]

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.09842.pdf

(equation (3.18) on page 18 of the pdf file)

Here is what the code looks like from the downloaded latex file:

```
\begin{multline}
G_{(u,v)}^{w,2,1}(t)=
-\frac{1}{tp_2}\times \\
\dfrac{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\sum}}}\limits_{l=0}^r\left(
   \splitdfrac{\splitdfrac{z_1^{w+2}(z_2^{w-(v-u)_+-l+1}z_3^{(u-v)_++l}-z_3^{w-(v-u)_+-l+1}z_2^{(u-v)_++l})}
                                   {- z_2^{w+2}(z_1^{w-(v-u)_+-l+1}z_3^{(u-v)_++l}-z_3^{w-(v-u)_+-l+1}z_1^{(u-v)_++l})}}{+z_3^{w+2}(z_1^{w-(v-u)_+-l+1}z_2^{(u-v)_++l}-z_2^{w-(v-u)_+-l+1}z_1^{(u-v)_++l})}
\right)}
{z_1^{w+3}(z_2^{w+2}-z_3^{w+2})-z_2^{w+3}(z_1^{w+2}-z_3^{w+2})+z_3^{w+3}(z_1^{w+2}-z_2^{w+2})}.
\label{21final}
\end{multline}
```

I am trying to reproduce this but without the dependencies of needing to use his template. Copying this verbatim will not work. Ideally I would just be able to copy and paste something similar to this and have it work without breaking.

I am using the Overleaf platform.

Answer (score 1):

The code you obtained from the paper's LateX source file isn't bad, overall. However, it does have a few shortcomings, in terms of math typography, that wouldn't pass muster with someone with a discerning eye. In no particular order:

- Too much white space below the third row in the numerator. This, in turn, makes the tall parentheses too big. This issue is caused by how the pair of `\splitdfrac` directives are employed. To avoid the unsightly gap at the bottom, one needs to replace

  ```
  \splitdfrac{\splitdfrac{...}{...}}{...}
  ```

  with

  ```
  \splitdfrac{...}{\splitdfrac{...}{...}}
  ```
- Failure to increase the size of the main pairs of parentheses in each of the three rows of the numerator and in the denominator.
- The subscript `+` terms aren't set sufficiently low, making them interfere visually with the subsequent `+` and `-` terms. See the code below for a way to improve the situation.
- The denominator is awfully close to the main horizontal fraction rule, as are the tall parentheses that encase the numerator terms. See the way I use `\mathstrut` directives for a way to fix this.
- Insufficient whitespace to the left of the `\times` symbol in row 1, as the code treats it as if it were a unary rather than a binary operator.

**Before** (copied from the OP's query):

[image]

**After** (generated by the code shown below):

[image]

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article} % 'leqno' option just for this example
\newcommand{\xx}{^{}_{\mkern-2mu+}} % lower the "+" symbol and snug it up to the closing parenthesis
\usepackage{mathtools,relsize}

\counterwithin{equation}{section} % just for this example  

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{3}           % just for this example
\setcounter{equation}{17}         % just for this example

\begin{multline} \label{21final}
G_{(u,v)}^{w,2,1}(t) = -\smash[b]{\frac{1}{tp_2}}\times{} \\
\frac{
\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\sum}}}_{l=0}^r
\left(
    \splitdfrac{ z_1^{w+2}\bigl(z_2^{w-(v-u)\xx-l+1}z_3^{(u-v)\xx+l}
                      -z_3^{w-(v-u)\xx-l+1}z_2^{(u-v)\xx+l}\,\bigr)}
   {\splitdfrac{-z_2^{w+2}\bigl(z_1^{w-(v-u)\xx-l+1}z_3^{(u-v)\xx+l}
                      -z_3^{w-(v-u)\xx-l+1}z_1^{(u-v)\xx+l}\,\bigr)}      
               {+z_3^{w+2}\bigl(z_1^{w-(v-u)\xx-l+1}z_2^{(u-v)\xx+l}
                      -z_2^{w-(v-u)\xx-l+1}z_1^{(u-v)\xx+l}\,\bigr)}}
\right)_{\mathstrut}}% end of numerator
{ z_1^{w+3}\bigl(z_2^{w+2}-z_3^{w+2}\bigr)
 -z_2^{w+3}\bigl(z_1^{w+2}-z_3^{w+2}\bigr)
 +z_3^{w+3}\bigl(z_1^{w+2}-z_2^{w+2}\bigr)^{\mathstrut}}\,.
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loading these packages fixed it:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{relsize}
```

Comment: This could be an edit to the question.